# Fitting a Quadratic-Plateau in python - scipy optimize.curve_fit a function returns value depends on a conditional parameter

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit a Quadratic-plateau model to agricultural data. In particular, it's Nitrogen fertilization and corn yield response to it. It's a common practice in research.

It's very common to do it using R, like in this following example-
https://gradcylinder.org/quad-plateau/

but it lacks examples and resources when it comes to python. I've managed to find a great library, called eonr (https://eonr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that does what I'm looking for (and much more) but i need more flexibility and more options for visualization.

Through the eonr gallery I found the function it uses and the parameters for the fitting done by scipy.curve_fit.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = df['N_Rate'].values.reshape(-1)
y = df['Yield'].values.reshape(-1)

def quad_plateau(x, b0, b1, b2):
    crit_x = -b1/(2*b2)
    y = 0
    y += (b0 + b1*x + b2*(x**2)) * (x < crit_x)
    y += (b0 - (b1**2) / (4*b2)) * (x >= crit_x)
    return y

guess=[10,0.0001,-10]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(quad_plateau,x,y,p0=guess,maxfev=1500)

plt.plot(x, y, 'bo')
plt.plot(x, quad_plateau(x, *popt), 'r-')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I overcame a lot of issues but i can't understand why the grapsh shows only the linear part of the graph... what am i doing wrong?
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You should check the function. For the initial guess it gives a straight line. Either the initial guess is very far from the actual parameters or the function is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As so often, the problem comes down to (already mentioned by Christian K. in a comment) starting values. It should work with some easy guesses, though. On top we can simplify our lives by choosing a different representation of the parabola, namely `y = y0 + a * ( x - x0 )**2`. This allows us directly to see the position of the extremum and the value it has at this point. The important point is to make sure that the position of the extremum is within data range or on the right of it. If it would be on the left, the function just gives a flat line in the data range. So in the Levenberg-Marquardt of `curve_fit` the derivatives wrt `a` and `x0` have no effect. Only `y0` is fitted to the rms.

The final code looks like

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.stats import norm # only for generic data with errors


def quad_plateau(x, x0, a, y0): # much shorter version in this representation
    return y0 + a * ( x - x0 )**2 * (x < x0 )


guess=[ 150, -0.15, 10000 ] # initial values for generic data
xl = np.linspace( 0, 350, 120 ) # xdata
yl = quad_plateau( xl, *guess)
error = norm.rvs( scale= 505, size = len( yl ) )
yn = yl + error # ydata with errors

# making some automated guesses for initial parameters
myguessy0 = np.mean( yn )
myguessx0 = np.mean( xl )
myguessa = -1 # could be elaborated more, but works for now
theguess = [ myguessy0, myguessa, myguessy0 ]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(
    quad_plateau,
    xl, yn,
    p0=theguess
)

print( popt )

xfull = np.linspace( 0, 350, 700 )
yfull =  quad_plateau( xfull, *popt )

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )
ax.scatter( xl, yn )
ax.plot( xfull, yfull )

plt.show()
```

works nicely, but might need some update in the bigger picture of large data sets.